# Round off all computed textbox decimal places into 2

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am having a problem with my script, I want to round of all the result on text boxes simultaneously every changes that I am making on every textboxes.

I am talking about hundreds of textboxes that will round off after every changes/input on textboxes.

Anyways here is my sample code of my work.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="1.1251112314555" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox2" value="1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox3" value="1" readonly/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox4" value="1" readonly/>
<br/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("input[type=text]").blur(function() {

  totalad3 = parseInt(textbox) * parseInt(textbox2);
    totalad4 = parseInt(textbox) + parseInt(textbox2);

  $('#textbox3').val(totalad3);  
  $('#textbox4').val(totalad4+"%");    

    var num = parseFloat($("input[type=text]").val());
    var new_num = $("input[type=text]").val(num.toFixed(2));
});
```

[image]

Comment: Two things: 1. JavaScript and jQuery are not alternatives to one another. You mean "With the DOM' and "With jQuery". You're using JavaScript either way. 2. You have your "with the DOM" and "with jQuery" backward. `getElementById` is using the DOM directly. `$(...)` is using jQuery.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: What process populates the textboxes? Why not apply the rounding to that process and apply a decimal mask to the textboxes so nobody can add more than 2 decimals in the first place?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. What text boxes do you want to update? How do you want to update them? There are various issues with your current code, but we can't really help you without knowing what you mean to do.

Comment: I am not using the jQuery and javascript at the same time just to be clear, I am now working on javascript because I am more familiar with this compare to jQuery.

Comment: What is happening right now on that code is it rounds off all the decimal places but it just replicate the value of the first textbox.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What I want to happen is that every onblur of textbox all the textboxes will automatically roundoff after the computation that I've made

Comment: *"I am not using the jQuery and javascript at the same time just to be clear"* Yes, you are. Again: JavaScript and jQuery are not alternatives to one another. You mean "With the DOM" (e.g., `getElementById` and such) vs. "With jQuery". You're using JavaScript either way. JavaScript is a language, not an API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to update values in each input with rounded values on blur event of any input, in the handler function get all the inputs and then iterate over each input and change its value. something like this:

```js
$('input[type=text]').on('blur', function() {
    var inputs = $('input[type=text]');
    inputs.each(function(){
        var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
        var new_num = num.toFixed(2);
        $(this).val(new_num);
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="textbox" value="1.1251112314555" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox2" value="1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox3" value="1" readonly/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox4" value="1" readonly/>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"/>
```

Comment: this is what I am looking for, I am trying to apply it with my computation, thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much @Dij your code works perfectly with my script, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> hundreds of textboxes that will round off after every changes/input on
>   textboxes.

If I understand your requirement correctly..

```js
$("input[type=text]").blur(function() {
     
        // console.log("Which textbox has changes?", $(this).val() );
         
         // Get current input value
         var currentInputValue = parseFloat($(this).val());
         
         // Round them to 2 decimal
         var roundedValue = currentInputValue.toFixed(2);
         
         // Update back to textbox
         $(this).val( roundedValue );
         
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="1.1251112314555" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox2" value="1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox3" value="1" readonly/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox4" value="1" readonly/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox5" value="123.2323" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox6" value="1.444" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox7" value="23.23235" />
<br/>
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"/>
```

Comment: yes I have some textboxes that populates a lot of textboxes and what I want to happpen is to round off into 2 decimal places only after the computation that I already made. no need for button to trigger, what I want to happen is the script will execute for all the textboxes every onblue of single textbox

Answer (score 0):

Another way using **Array.from with Map function**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[type=text]").on('blur', function(){
            Array.from($("input[type=text]"), (el, i) => $(el).val(parseFloat($(el).val()).toFixed(2)));
        })
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="textbox" value="1.1251112314555" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox2" value="1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox3" value="1" readonly/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox4" value="1" readonly/>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" />
```